# Installing multiple ServerRoles with PowerShell

Tags: powershell, roles

I wrote a PowerShell script for Server 2008 R2, to check if certain roles and features are installed and if they aren't to install them (of course I imported the ServerManager Module at first) i.e.:

```
if ((Get-WindowsFeature AS-NET-Framework).Installed -eq 0)
{$InstallFeatures += "AS-NET-Framework,"
Write-Host "AS-NET-Framework will be added"}

if ((Get-WindowsFeature GPMC).Installed -eq 0)
{$InstallFeatures += "GPMC,"
 Write-Host "GPMC will be added"}
```

but when I invoke

```
Add-WindowsFeature $InstallFeatures
```

it gives an Error that the name wasn't found.
Somehow PS doesn't accept the comma as delimiter in a string.

But if you type

```
Add-WindowsFeature AS-NET-Framwork,GPMC
```

in the console it works just fine.

Is there any way to to invoke the `Add-WindowsFeature` with all the parameters I need in one line without creating a new variable for each check, because then I'd only need one reboot for all missing roles and features?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try declaring :

```
 [string[]]$InstallFeatures = @()
```

before your code.

```
if ((Get-WindowsFeature AS-NET-Framework).Installed -eq 0)
{$InstallFeatures += "AS-NET-Framework"
Write-Host "AS-NET-Framework will be added"}
if ((Get-WindowsFeature GPMC).Installed -eq 0)
{$InstallFeatures += "GPMC"
 Write-Host "GPMC will be added"}
```

The signature for `Get-WindowsFeature` is:

```
Get-WindowsFeature [[-Name] <string[]>] [-logPath <string>] [<CommonParameters>]
```

the parameter name  accept a `string array` and not a `string`. 
In your code you  need to remove the commas as I wrote above.

Comment: @IronGibbet Always happy to help. To avoid this errors in future  take a look at miscrosoft msdn/technet to see cmdlet's signatures!